# PHP - Proxy Script

Tags: php, mysql, proxy

I've been reading this book about PHP and MySQL and at the end of each chapter it asks you some questions for you to research about and one of them I don't really get:

> *What is a Proxy script? When might a proxy script be necessary?*

I hope you could help me answering this question because I don't really know what it is (*I do know what a proxy server is though*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From WikiPedia's article on [Proxy Servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)

> In computer networks, a proxy server is a server (a computer system or
>   an application) that acts as an intermediary for requests from clients
>   seeking resources from other servers. A client connects to the proxy
>   server, requesting some service, such as a file, connection, web page,
>   or other resource available from a different server and the proxy
>   server evaluates the request as a way to simplify and control its
>   complexity.

That explains it pretty much. So basically, a PHP proxy script can be used to access the blocked content i.e. websites in a network i.e. a college's WiFi network.

For an example, suppose facebook.com is blocked by your college's WiFi and you want to access it then a PHP proxy script might come in handy. Which will take requests from you and send it to the facebook on your behalf and sends the received data back to you. So you're not directly communicating with the facebook's server but that proxy script is doing that job for you.

Here's a simple PHP proxy script I found from a quick search that you might find helpful : [Simple-php-proxy-script](https://github.com/Alexxz/Simple-php-proxy-script)

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me understand it better, Have a nice day.